# Legend is not sizing and being positioned properly in PyCharm and other IDEs (seaborn)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, seaborn

When creating a pairplot using Seaborn in PyCharm, the legend provided is going inside the plots/tables when using `plt.show()` to display plot. This results in it being illegible.

Here is the code producing the pairplot:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.pairplot(tips, hue='sex')
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot produced by the code above:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with the code, seaborn or matplotlib. It is a problem with PyCharm and some other IDEs. This can be demonstrated by using `Pairplot.savefig`

Here is the image returned by the same:
[image]

As you can see the plot is perfectly spaced.